# GoRouter | Extra is cleared on hot reload

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web, gorouter

Let's say I have a route defined as the following:

```
GoRoute(
  path: Screen.classDetail.path,
  builder: (context, state) => AdminClassScreen(
    classItem: state.extra as Class,
  ),
),
```

and I navigate to it using

```
router.push(Screen.classDetail.path, extra: extra);
```

When I hot reload on Web, the application goes into a bad state because the object I am passing in as extra is not preserved. Is there a way around this?

Comment: As a workaround for the gui development stages you can pass the extra as a nullable object (Class?), and if it's null to use a hard coded object (inside AdminClassScreen).

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering the same issue for two days now. So far as i understand from my researches,for go_router package there is no page refresh support on object-passed pages via extra .

Edit: i tried 2 more routing packages(auto_router , beamer). For object passed pages , all of the packages failing on hot reload. But i solved my problem by passing String pathParameter instead of object. Which this string is the parsed string of an index number. Then after passing to the page , parsed this string to the int again. Then i reached my object from an object list via this index number.

Hope this helps someone.